# How to download yum packages on windows (or online in browser)

Tags: linux, centos, yum, packages, rpm

I am newbie to linux and just started using it at home, but I don't have internet connection at home, and in office I have good internet but using windows,

I just want to download yum packages on my windows and then I want to use them on linux (centos) at home, do do you know any tools or online service so I can do this, if possible I want to also utilize some commands like `groupinstall`

basically I want to install gnome 3 now on centos, I trying to download all package like in yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"

i am aware of this sites,

http://pkgs.org/

http://rpmfind.net

Comment: basically i want to install gnome 3 now on centos, i trying to download all package like in `yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the rpms packages that accompany the CentOS distribution in
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/ and the just navigate to your particular release (ie 6.4).

BUT what you are trying to do is quite a bit more complex that just downloading a single rpm. rpms have dependecies and especially in `groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"` you are going to need dozens of rpms.

What you can do is use the CentOS DVD that already contains all the rpms and direct yum to use the DVD as the repo. So do something like this: 
Create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-DVD.repo` as

```
[c6-dvd]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Media
baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
        file:///media/cdrom/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

and then do `yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c6-dvd install whatever`
Just make sure you add the correct mount point for your DVD in the above file.

obviously you will not get updates for your installed packages but without an internet connection that is a bit complex

Comment: yes, i know that method to isntall from cd or any local repo, but don't you know any way to download packages online with all of their dependenceis, thanks thanoks, hope i could vote up your answers.

Comment: That is what tools like yum are for. They download each package, resolve the dependencies and download those packages resolve their dependencies till there are no more dependencies and proceed with the installation. You can do it manually checking each file for dependencies (extremely time consuming) or you can write a tool in Windows to do that for you.

Comment: yes yes, i am looking for some tool like yum in windows (utilize downlaod function only).

Comment: as far as I know it does not exist. You can try to run yum under cygwin with custom repos and set to --downloadonly . Other than that you need to write your own tools.

Comment: ohh, very thanks thanosk, does cygwin support yum too?

Comment: never tried it. you would definitely need python and install everything manually instead of using apt-cyg but other than that I have no idea. As I said originally it is a million times easier to use the DVD or even clone the whole CentOS repo to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: ok i am trying with cygwin, but its saying yum command not found

Comment: no it is not part of cygwin. you need to try to compile it under cygwin.